# How do I pull a number out of an API request?

Tags: python, api

I know I am stupid, feel free to hate me, but...

I want to pull a number out of an API request, the API returns this:

`{"bitcoin":{"gbp":24141}}`

I am trying to store the number (24141) as a variable in python.
I've tried this: `btc_price_gbp = (requests.get(url).json()["gbp"])`
but it returns this:
line 4, in 
btc_price_gbp = (requests.get(url).json()["gbp"])
KeyError: 'gbp'

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

`{"gbp":24141}` is the value for the key `bitcoin`, so try try indexing it like this:

```py
btc_price_gbp = (requests.get(url).json()["bitcoin"]["gbp"])
```